# Error: Bad Request while submitted a form

Tags: php, apache, cookies

[image]

Hi everyone,

This is the problems i'm getting. What type of error is this? Is this a Browser issue? Is there any solution? any help would appreciated.

Comment: Can you check your form action ?

Comment: If your form uses 'get' method, I suggest you use 'post' method instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says:

> Size of a request header field exceeds server limit.

Then:

`Cookie: ...`

So, it means that the client is sending out too much data in the `Cookie` header for the server to accept.

Found this: [Request header field exceeding server limit (Super User)](https://superuser.com/questions/284617/request-header-field-exceeding-server-limit).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's at [login form](https://ah37wy2m5hdn.phyauraemr.com/interface/login/login_frame.php) that you are getting the error. I'm not getting the error. Anyway, try other browsers and clean your browser cache and cookies to make sure it's not some kind of malfunction at client-side.